# Jquery datapicker requires to be selected twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-email

Thanks for taking the time out of your day to assist me. 
What i am looking to get help with is my datepicker. I am building a small webform that acts as a template for an email. So the idea is to fill in the form, hit create and it populates a email with the form information. 
However, my datepicker requires me to select the date twice until it prints the correct date to the email. The first selection will result in nothing, and 3rd attempt would result in 2nd selection being output and so on.

I am using Jquery 1.12.4 and my code is as follows:

JS:

```
    $(function(){
        $( "#IncidentDateInput" ).datepicker({
                  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            }); 
    });


    function updateMailString() {           
            mailString = '?subject=' + encodeURIComponent($('#subject').val())
                + '&body=Agent Name: ' + encodeURIComponent($('#AgentNameInput').val()) 
                +"%0D%0AMDN: " +encodeURIComponent($('#MDNInput').val())
                +"%0D%0ADevice: " +encodeURIComponent($('#DeviceInput').val())
                +"%0D%0AIssue: " +encodeURIComponent($('#IssueInput').val())
                +"%0D%0ADate: " +encodeURIComponent($('#IncidentDateInput').val());
            var receiver = encodeURIComponent($('#ReceiverInput').val());
            $('#mail-link').attr('href',  'mailto:' + receiver + mailString);
        }


$( "#IncidentDateInput" ).focusout(function() { updateMailString(); });
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="IncidentDateInput"  />
```

Any insight would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `change` instead of `focusout`. When using `focusout` input remains empty and `updateMailString` function is called. On using `change` function, after input(datepicker) is changed then `updateMailString` function is called

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/Lx7a32m7/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#IncidentDateInput').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  });
  $("#IncidentDateInput").change(function() {
    updateMailString();
  });
})

function updateMailString() {
  mailString = '?subject=' + encodeURIComponent($('#subject').val()) + "%0D%0ADate: " + encodeURIComponent($('#IncidentDateInput').val());
  var receiver = encodeURIComponent($('#ReceiverInput').val());
  $('#mail-link').attr('href', 'mailto:' + receiver + mailString);
  alert($('#mail-link').attr('href'))
}
```

Comment: Life saver! Thank you.